# How to set the text at particular id in dynamic generated Button

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have the following code. In this i have dynamically generated buttons.when click the button it shows the timepicker. My problem is to set the time for clicked button but it set the text at the last button how to set the value at clicked button...

```
public void addButton(int value) {
    list.removeAllViews();

    for (i=0 ; i < value; i++) {
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Add Time");
        button.setId(i);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                new TimePickerDialog(MedInfo.this, onTimeListener, mCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false)
                        .show();
                btn_cnt = v.getId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+btn_cnt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        list.addView(button);
    }
}


TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        String AM_PM;
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (hourOfDay < 12) {
            AM_PM = "AM";

        } else {
            AM_PM = "PM";

        }

        long start_time = DateTimeUtils.getTimeInMillis(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        long mseconds = DateTimeUtils.getFirstMillis(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        time = start_time + mseconds;

        button.settext(time);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    }
};
```

any help will be appreciable...

Edit :

error log:

```
10-29 15:07:32.478: E/AndroidRuntime(6401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 15:07:32.478: E/AndroidRuntime(6401): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 15:07:32.478: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at com.example.medicationreminder.MedInfo$MyOnTimeSetListenter.onTimeSet(MedInfo.java:237)
10-29 15:07:32.478: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.tryNotifyTimeSet(TimePickerDialog.java:130)
10-29 15:07:32.478: E/AndroidRuntime(6401):     at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:115)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like to update the text of particular Button

```
Button b=(Button)list.getChildAt(btn_cnt);
b.settext(time);
```

As you are storing the `Button Id` in **btn_cnt**, so can get the view with `getChildAt(position)`

Where **list** is your `Layout` where you adding the `Button dynamically`.

```
public void addButton(int value) {
    list.removeAllViews();

    for (i=0 ; i < value; i++) {
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Add Time");
        button.setId(i);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                new TimePickerDialog(MedInfo.this, onTimeListener, mCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false)
                        .show();
                btn_cnt = v.getId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+btn_cnt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        list.addView(button);
    }
}


TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        String AM_PM;
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (hourOfDay < 12) {
            AM_PM = "AM";

        } else {
            AM_PM = "PM";

        }

        long start_time = DateTimeUtils.getTimeInMillis(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        long mseconds = DateTimeUtils.getFirstMillis(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        time = start_time + mseconds;

        Button b=(Button)list.getChildAt(btn_cnt);
        b.settext(time);

        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    }
};
```

Edit:- You can use `List` instead of `Array` for retrieving all the time from Button.

```
List<String> listOfDate=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<list.getChildCount();i++)
        {
            Button b=(Button)list.getChildAt(i);
            listOfDate.add(b.getText().toString());

        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: this shows this error... Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
  Assignment
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement

Comment: @Arut Button b=(Button)list.getChildAt(btn_cnt);
b.settext(time); try like this.

Comment: @Arut sure, you can ask .. I ll try to help you out.

Comment: in above one i want to get the time for each button ..i got the values using array is that good or use some other way..

Comment: I didn't use the gettext of button because i convert the time into some other formats...

Comment: thanks bro ..but the Button will be 11:00 AM like this..so i want to use the time ..

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to implement a custom `OnTimeSetListener` which can keep reference to the clicked button. Before you show the time picker, inform the custom listener which button was clicked. See code below:

```
public void addButton(int value) {
    list.removeAllViews();

    for (i=0 ; i < value; i++) {
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Add Time");
        button.setId(i);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                // set the button which was clicked
                onTimeListener.setClickedButton((Button)v);
                new TimePickerDialog(this, onTimeListener, mCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false)
                        .show();
                btn_cnt = v.getId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+btn_cnt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        list.addView(button);
    }
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeListener = new MyOnTimeSetListenter();

class MyOnTimeSetListenter implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private Button button;

    public void setClickedButton(Button button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i2) {
        String AM_PM;
        Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (hourOfDay < 12) {
            AM_PM = "AM";

        } else {
            AM_PM = "PM";

        }

        long start_time = DateTimeUtils.getTimeInMillis(hourOfDay, minute, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        long mseconds = DateTimeUtils.getFirstMillis(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        time = start_time + mseconds;

        this.button.settext(time);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourOfDay);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `MediaInfo.this` while creating the dialog `new TimePickerDialog`. Use `Context` or `Activity` or `this` depending on where your code is placed in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a global variable and set its value onTimeListener and whenever required setText(global_variable)

Comment: once you have the time value you can set it on any control of the page
make button declaration global too and then try

Comment: my button is dynamic one. I think you are not understand my question.

Comment: i have time value.. the problem is i want to set the different time for dynamically generated buttons...