# How to set the time picker Minimum and Maximum values dynamically in android?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-timepicker

I have time picker,i want to set the time picker min and max values dynamically For Example : get the current time plus 2:30hrs as minimum value and max value is 11:00 pm.

**Timepicker Dialog**

```
public class Time_picker extends DialogFragment{

OnTimeSetListener ontimeSet;

int minHour;
int minMinute;

private int maxHour = 24;
private int maxMinute =00;
DateFormat dateFormat;
public Time_picker() {

}

public void setCallBack(OnTimeSetListener ontime) {

    ontimeSet = ontime;

}

private int hours, minutes;
@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
    hours = args.getInt("hours");
    minutes = args.getInt("minute");

    minHour = hours;//current time plus 2:30hrs
    minMinute = -1;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TimePickerDialog _time = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), ontimeSet, hours, minutes,false){

        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{
                boolean validTime;
                if(hourOfDay < minHour) {
                    validTime = false;
                }
                else if(hourOfDay == minHour) {
                    validTime = minute >= minMinute;
                }
                else if(hourOfDay == maxHour) {
                    validTime = minute <= maxMinute;
                }
                else {
                    validTime = true;
                }

                if(validTime) {
                    hours = hourOfDay;
                    minutes = minute;
                }
                else {
                    updateTime(hours, minutes);
                }

            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    };
    return _time;
}
}
```

Some time it shows plus 2:30 hrs correctly but come time it shows 1 hrs back in time picker.am not able to find out the issue.Can any one know help me to solve this issue.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19653820/2982225) might help you